# Pandas get_dummies() with for loop inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a one-hot encoder. When I try with just one country, it works, but when I do the loop, it returns an error. Here a few rows of the DF, so you can imagine.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"country":["United States", "India, United States", "Italy, India"],
"listed_in":["Comedies", "Action, Comedies", "Adventure, Action"]})
```

Next, I isolated the countries doing the following code:

```
countries = list(netflix_clean["country"].apply(str).unique())

only_first_country = []

for country in countries:
    only_first_country.extend(re.findall(r"^(.+?),", country))

countries_clean = list(set(only_first_country))
```

Then, I tried it inputting just one country, to see if the function worked (which it does).

```
def dummy_country_genre(df, country):
    country_1 = df[df["country"].str.contains(country, case=False, regex=False, na=False)]
    
    return country_1[["listed_in"]].unstack().str.get_dummies(sep=", ").sum(level = 0).rename(index={"listed_in":country})

dummy_country_genre(netflix_clean, "United States")
```

But when I do it looping it returns the following error: *'list' object has no attribute 'upper'*

Here's the code that fails:

```
def dummy_country_genre_test2(df, country):
    ctry = [c for c in country]
    country_1 = df[df["country"].str.contains(ctry, case=False, regex=False, na=False)]
    
    return country_1[["listed_in"]].unstack().str.get_dummies(sep=", ").sum(level = 0).rename(index={"listed_in":ctry})

dummy_country_genre_test2(netflix_clean, countries_clean)
```

**EDIT**

I solved the issue with that code, just in case anyone else needs it:

```
def dummy_country_genre_test2(df, country):
    list_of = []
    for c in country:
        country_1 = df[df["country"].str.contains(c, case=False, regex=False, na=False)]
        df2 = country_1[["listed_in"]].unstack().str.get_dummies(sep=", ").sum(level = 0).rename(index={"listed_in":c})
        list_of.append(df2)
          
    result = pd.concat(list_of).fillna(0).astype(int)
    
    return result

dummy_country_genre_test2(netflix_clean, countries_clean)
```

Comment: @BillHuang Now there is some data showing how the DF looks like and the step by step that I followed. Let me know if everything is okay and thanks!

Comment: Unless I am missing it, where in the shown code are you using upper?

Comment: @itprorh66, that's the main issue, that I didn't use upper. Although I managed to solve the error. I will edit the post, just in case someone else faces the same error